# C/C++, GetLastError() и errno()

Tags: c++

Я бы хотел разобраться в том, каким образом названные функции реализуют сохранение информации о последней возникшей ошибке **в текущем вызывающем потоке**.

Как это реализуется?

И каким способом можно реализовать аналогичный функционал? Ну, например, предоставить для своей библиотеки аналог **GetLastError()**/**errno()**.

Comment: Зачем вам аналог? Вы можете пользоваться этими функциями. [SetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680627(v=vs.85).aspx), [set_errno](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/set-errno)

Comment: Я хочу понять, каким способом это реализуется.

Comment: Просто thread_local переменная.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начиная с 11 стандарта (обоих языков) можно использовать спецификатор хранения [thread_local](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thread_local). При использовании компиляторов, которые его не поддерживают - аналогичные функции ОС, например [Thread Local Storage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/using-thread-local-storage) в WinAPI. Пример использования TLS в библиотеке можно посмотреть здесь: [Using Thread Local Storage in a Dynamic-Link Library](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/Dlls/using-thread-local-storage-in-a-dynamic-link-library)